# How to setup webpack for supporting ES6 Modules in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using Webpack for bundle client and server code, so my `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = [
  { /* client config */ },
  { /* server config */ },
];
```

I want to write ES6 (modules) in both and transpile code to ES5 using Babel.

For client, this can be done with `babel-loader`:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude:  /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: [
      'react',
      [
        'env',
        {
          targets: {
            'browsers': 'last 2 versions',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
}
```

Based on this, I wrote babel loader for server:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude:  /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: [
      'react',
      [
        'env',
        {
          targets: {
            'node': 'current',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
}
```

> Something tells me that `babel-loader` will never work for this purpose.

After ran `webpack`, bundles are right located but server entry point (`server.js`) aren't transpiled correctly:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Generally when we want to transpile Node code, we would use `babel-cli` package and add a script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src -d dist"
}
```

and manually:

`npm run build`

My question is: How to setup ES6 transpiling with Babel for Node inside `webpack.config.js`?

---

+BONUS

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

const babelRcClient = {
  presets: [
    'react',
    [
      'env',
      {
        targets: {
          'browsers': 'last 2 versions',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
const babelRcServer = {
  presets: [
    'react',
    [
      'env',
      {
        targets: {
          'node': 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};

const babelLoaderClient = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude:  /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: babelRcClient,
};
const babelLoaderServer = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude:  /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: babelRcServer,
};

module.exports = [
  {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './shared/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        babelLoaderClient,
      ],
    },
    plugins: [],
  },
  {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './server/server.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
      filename: 'server.js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    },
    externals: [ /^(?!\.|\/).+/i, ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        babelLoaderServer,
      ],
    },
    plugins: [],
  },
]
```

Comment: Are you running the original source by chance? There should be no import statements at all, not only does webpack handle `import` / `export` out of the box, but with your current Babel configuration they would be transpiled away before getting passed to webpack (it would be better to leave the `import`s to webpack, instead of transpiling them).

Comment: @MichaelJungo Sorry, what you mean about "leave import to webpack instead of transpiling them"?

Comment: I noticed you are using webpack v1. I think this doesn't support `import` out of box - maybe here lies the problem. I cannot find source of that, but I think I read about this today. I will try to find source, but you can try bumping webpack or including some kind of loader in the meantime.

Comment: @Morishiri In `package.json`: `"webpack": "^3.6.0"
`

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi I mean that you should not let Babel transpile ES modules (`import`/`export`) to `require`, because webpack will handle them, and leaving them as ES modules enables certain webpack features, such as [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/). Back to my question, do you run the original source (`./server/server.js`) or the produced bundle (`./build/server.js`)?

Comment: Oh, I got confused as you are not following this: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

Comment: @MichaelJungo Solved! Actually my setup is fully okay and working. I just confused the execution command. I was running `node ./server/serve.js` (not bundled) instead of `node ./build/server.js` (bundled)! Now I'm deleting this question because there is no problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying

```
targets: {
    'node': 'current',
}
```

you are telling `babel` to transpile your code to `node` version which you are using to transpile the code.

Are you using the same node version on production?

Try specifying numeric `node` version, e.g. `6.11.2` and then run transpilation.

Another thing you can do is tell babel to leave ES6 modules in ES6 way and don't replace it with `commonjs` approach (which is default) by setting:

```
targets: {
    'node': ...,
}, 
modules: false
```

Comment: Yeah, I want to transpile node code for current node version (which not supports ES6 Modules). By setting `modules: false` option, bundled code still as before. Same syntax error for `import` token.

Comment: Is there any possibility that you can prepare minimal code example where that happens? What node version are you running?

Comment: Another idea came up: You are transpiling only `js` files. Are your `react` components also `js`? Or is it `jsx`?

Comment: My Node is up to date `v8.6.0`. About React component (all are `.js`), I don't even include them when `import` syntax error occurs.

Comment: Editing question with my full `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score -1):

This thing worked for me. Try and check once.

```
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    include: [].concat(
                        path.resolve('./app') //path to your application
                    ),
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                }
```

Comment: Did it and: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: Have you setup your .babelrc. It should look something like this
`{
 "presets": [
  ["es2015", {
   "comment": true,
   "modules": false
  }],
  "react",
  "airbnb",
  "survivejs-kanban"
 ]
}
`

Comment: what this has to do with jsx his asking about node!